# Among Find, Single, First, which one is the fastest?

Tags: c#

I want to minimize the time needed to retrieve a single unique element from a list.
Which one is the fastest method among `Find`, `Single` and `First`?
Note that the searching key is a unique id.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The *fastest* (for a large set) would be to have them keyed against a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and use that.

`Single` and `First` do different things; `Single` always iterates the entire set, even if it finds it at the start of the list, so `First` would usually be quicker than `Single` since it short-circuits.

Comment: Shouldn't we also consider semantics of the provided methods? 
For me Single means, that it is expected that there will be only one matching item whereas First means just grab the first item, but it might be that there are several more ones. From a semantic point of view I mostly would prefer Single (GetById) and regarding performance I would go for First.

Answer (score 31):

`First` will be faster than `Single`, because it can terminate as soon as it's found the match. On the other hand, this means it *doesn't* validate that only one item matched the predicate.

`Find` should be as fast as `First`, but is less portable as it will only work on lists. If you're using LINQ in general, I would *try* to stick to LINQ operators unless there's a definite benefit in using an alternative.

As Marc says, if you're going to do this regularly you should use a `Dictionary<,>`. You can use the `ToDictionary` operator to do this easily:

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
// Now you can look up by ID really quickly
```

Obviously creating the dictionary takes some time to start with, so you'd only want to do this if you *are* searching multiple times.

Comment: @usr makes an interesting point. If he is correct would it not be faster to use `Find()`?

Comment: @CodeBlend: Maybe. In reality, I doubt that the difference would be significant, and they'd both be "O(n), finishing when they found a match". I would generally use the LINQ methods for increased generality unless I could prove that the difference is significant. Using a dictionary would definitely be better for multiple lookups, of course.

Answer (score 3):

They are different methods.
`Find` is defined in `List<T>`, it's almost the same as `First` that is defined in `Enumerable.cs` as an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. Both of them will return if a conditioned item is found(no need to loop through the whole collection), so they have slight performance difference.

While `Single` returns the conditioned item, and also guarantees that this item is the only one that meets the condition. So in most circumstances `Single` is slower than `First`/`Find` because it needs to loop through the collection.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the existing answers: List.Find is much faster than IEnumerable.First because the first one can operate on the List's internal Array. The latter one has to go through the IList interface.

Answer (score 1):

Single goes on through the whole list to make sure that there is indeed only one, so it will always hit every item in the list.

Find and First will stop as soon as they hit a match. Find is actually closer to FirstOrDefault, as Find will return the default if no match is found. First will throw an exception.

Single: 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource result = e.Current;
                if (predicate(result))
                {
                    while (e.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (predicate(e.Current))
                        {
                            ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException();
                        }
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

First: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs

After some logic, it boils down to:

```
foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                found = true;
                return element;
            }
        }
```

Find:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
            if(match(_items[i])) {
                return _items[i];
            }
        }
```